# ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation with custom duration

Tags: android, animation, android-transitions

I'm making a scene transition for devices with API level 20+. It is working fine, but I want to set custom duration to make the transition. Is it possible ??

My code:

```
ActivityOptionsCompat options =

                ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this,
                        viewStart,
                        transitionName
                );

        ActivityCompat.startActivity(this, detailsIntent, options.toBundle());
```

Comment: you can customize trasition https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Shared-Element-Activity-Transition

Answer (score 13):

You can set the desired duration in the new started  activity, by adding:

```
    ChangeBounds bounds = new ChangeBounds();
    bounds.setDuration(2000);
    getWindow().setSharedElementEnterTransition(bounds);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read #5 of Mr saeed's link. Or you can try by java code:

```
Window window = getWindow();
TransitionSet set = new TransitionSet();
set.addTransition(new ChangeImageTransform());
set.addTransition(new ChangeBounds());
set.setDuration(duration);
set.addListener(yourTransitionListener)
window.setSharedElementEnterTransition(set);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple one-liner in Kotlin, just put it in the `onCreate()` of the Activity you're starting: `window.sharedElementEnterTransition.duration = 300`